# Ignore grep -v not query when empty pattern is passed?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a piece of code which is working as it should be but i want a different result. Let's say `$query_value` and `$not_query_value` is `empty`.

```
`sed -n "$dateRange" $error_log_file_name|egrep -i "($query_value)"|grep -E -i -v "($not_query_value)"|head -n $first_few_lines_value>>$extracted_log_path_value`
```

The output from `sed` is passed to grep. `grep` returns everything and `grep -V` returns nothing when empty pattern is passed. My desire is that `grep -V` should act like `grep` when `empty` patter is passed to it. I could achieve it by `if,else` conditions by checking whether empty pattern is not passed to grep -V. But i don't want to provide any checkpoint. Is there a way `grep -V` could be ignored when `$not_query_value` is not provided ?

An input sample is -

```
sed -n '/2018-02-19 00:0[0-9]/,/2018-02-19 23:59/p' "/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog_2.txt"|egrep -i "()"|grep -E -i -v "()"|head -n $first_few_lines_value>>$extracted_log_path_value;
```

which returns nothing. The expected output would be huge lines of log files like -

```
> 2018-02-19 00:01:03.668 Info: Merged 26 MB in 1 sec at 19 MB/sec to
> /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059de 2018-02-19 00:01:06.046 Info:
> Deleted 20 MB at 7321 MB/sec /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059db
> 2018-02-19 00:01:06.050 Info: Deleted 6 MB at 1546 MB/sec
> /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059da 2018-02-19 00:01:06.054 Info:
> Deleted 7 MB at 1988 MB/sec /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059dc
> 2018-02-19 00:10:00.406 Info: Saving /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059dd
> 2018-02-19 00:10:01.059 Info: Saved 6 MB in 1 sec at 9 MB/sec to
> /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059dd 2018-02-19 00:17:01.076 Info: Saving
> /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059df 2018-02-19 00:17:01.349 Info: Saved
> 6 MB at 22 MB/sec to /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059df 2018-02-19
> 00:17:01.375 Info: Merging 30 MB from
> /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059de, /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059dd,
> and /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059df to
> /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059e1, timestamp=15190204210766740
> 2018-02-19 00:17:04.285 Info: Merged 29 MB in 3 sec at 10 MB/sec to
> /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059e1 2018-02-19 00:17:07.209 Info:
> Deleted 26 MB at 922 MB/sec /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059de
> 2018-02-19 00:17:07.239 Info: Deleted 6 MB at 198 MB/sec
> /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059dd 2018-02-19 00:17:07.251 Info:
> Deleted 6 MB at 516 MB/sec /var/opt//Forests/Meters/000059df
> 2018-02-19 00:19:01.558 Info: Merging 1 MB from
> /var/opt//Forests/App-Services/00000a33 to
> /var/opt//Forests/App-Services/00000a35, timestamp=15190205407316140
> 2018-02-19 00:19:01.626 Info: Merged 2 MB at 29 MB/sec to
> /var/opt//Forests/App-Services/00000a35
```

which comes as expected till grep command but `grep -V {empty pattern}` reverses and returns nothing. I want something like when empty pattern is passed in `grep -V` it should be either not executed or act like grep (as grep returns everything in case of empty sequence).

Comment: Please, give an input sample, the expected output and explain how you initialized `$dateRange` for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @PierreFrançois added eample

Comment: @basari66 : Just to clarify - do you mean by "empty pattern" that the variables `query_value` and `not_query_value` contain the string *empty*? I ask because this sounds odd, but it seems to me that you are really meaning that.

Comment: $query_value and $not_query_value comes from a property file. so if not_query_value=              in the property file then it has nothing

Comment: @basari66, what do you mean by "don't want to provide any checkpoint"? Note that you can put logic *inside* the pipeline; ie. `${query_value:+-v}` will expand to `-v` only when `$query_value` is not empty or unset... or you could put the conditional in the pipeline: `... | if [[ $query_value ]]; then grep -v "$query_value"; else cat; fi | ...`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses from your grep -v condition to get the desired results.
Your code should be:

```
sed -n "$dateRange" "$error_log_file_name"|egrep -i "($query_value)"|grep -E -i -v "$not_query_value"|head -n $first_few_lines_value>>"$extracted_log_path_value"
```

Comment: The backticks around the whole command are surely not desired. Since output is redirected to a file, the command substitution has nothing to capture, so it's just an expensive noop.

Comment: Edited the answer to include the suggestions. Thanks Charles !

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - oh no.. The reason I put parentheses was so that I can perform AND / OR operation in grep -V...something like this - grep -V "(logic.*start|blood)"

Comment: @basari66 :  In that case, use egrep -v .

Comment: @ManiMaity - isn't grep -E means the same as egrep ?

Comment: @basari66 : I believe grep -E and egrep treat the parentheses differently.